# How do I perform a genie style animation without the need of a view controller to transition to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm allowing users to selected items to make favourites by tapping a heart. These items are shown in a collection view.

Each item has a small heart beside it. This is the heart the user taps to make the item a favourite.

In my navigation bar I have another heart and when this is tapped it takes the user to a page where all their favourite items are listed in a table view.

I've been working with custom transitions lately and have become quite comfortable with them. My problem in this case is I don't have a controller to transition to. All I want to do is have the collection view cell of the item that has been made a favourite shrink down into the heart in navigation bar.

**Here is my animator code:**

```
UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
UIViewController *toVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
UIView *fromView = fromVC.view;
UIView *toView = toVC.view;
UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
NSTimeInterval duration = [self transitionDuration:transitionContext];


NSIndexPath *selected = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems[0];
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:selected];

CGRect beginFrame = [containerView convertRect:cell.bounds fromView:cell];

// Would be safer to use container bounds here
CGRect endFrame = CGRectMake(264, 6, 0, 0);

// Presenting
if (toVC.isBeingPresented) {

    toView.frame = beginFrame;
    [containerView addSubview:toView];

    // Scale down to heart button
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations: ^{
     //   toView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0, 0.0);
        toView.frame = endFrame;

    } completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
    }];
}
```

I'm becoming confused because I have no toVC. I only have what I need which is the location of the selected cell and the location of the heart I want the cell to shrink into in my navigation bar.

[image]

This is all I really need for the animation. I am not transitioning to another controller. How can this be done? I'm sure Apple must provide a simple way to this.

I appreciate any help given.

Comment: Have a look here https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bcgenieeffect

Comment: @PawanSharma would this cause any issues when it comes to apple store acceptance?

Comment: I don't think Apple would have any problem with this animation.